# Is it possible to custom tokens on ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

My requirement is to create custom tokens, using smart contracts, based on the input data, that are locked forever ( non transferable )

Every request will create different tokens based on the input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Why wouldn't it be? You just need to restrict access to `transfer` and `transferFrom` so that they aren't available to the general public. You could not implement any transfer logic at all in these methods, but you run the risk of tokens being locked forever (unless you put the data storage into another contract), or restrict access to those methods with modifiers.

Comment: Yes I want them to be locked forever